# How to change a string globally in a MySQL database

Tags: php, drupal

I have an old drupal site that I'd like to upgrade, but I need to move all the site data files (like jpgs, gifs, etc.) from /files to /sites/default/files.

I'd like to use a PHP script or just a MySQL command to find any instance of /files/* and change it to /sites/default/files/* (without messing up the string in the * part of the name, of course!).

Is this pretty easy to do? Any pointers on a function I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does have some built-in string replacement functions.  How about something like this?

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field,'/files/','/sites/default/files/');
```

There's [other functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) you can use for more complex replacements (ie. regular expressions) if you need as well.

Comment: Looks like it should work. I'll try that in my test environment and see how it goes!

Comment: Just used this value (for a few different tables), and everything works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it's just a case of changing the 'files' path in the Drupal configuration.

Comment: Doing so would update all the new files, and change Drupal's internal use of the files, but would not update all the nodes with links/references to the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just changing the files table, you can do an UPDATE with SQL, like zombat said.  If you have a significant number of other instances of the paths ( IE - full HTML node bodies and the like ) your best bet would be to export the DB to a text file (can do it with mysqldump or the export feature of PHPMyAdmin) and then just update the strings there - either with a suitable text editor, a command-line tool like sed or a bunch of interns.

Comment: Ah - this would be another good option. Might do this for the next site I need to work on!